# Unable to restore nuget packages from private source in Rider 2019.3 running on Ubuntu

Tags: .net-core, nuget, rider

I'm unable to restore package for a solution in Rider 2019.3.
The error that happens is the following:

```html
17:12:23| Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'https://<private-source>/nuget/Farfetch-NuGet-LIVE/FindPackagesById()?id='My.Private.Package'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
  Authentication failed, see inner exception.
  Ssl error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
    at /jonnyzzz/MonoRuntime/Unix/mono/external/boringssl/ssl/handshake_client.c:1132
```

After a couple of weeks not working in the project, the error appeared. There were no auth modifications.
I'm able to see that the package exists in the nuget private repository (web search).

I've tried to clear every nuget cache folder as also the invalidating rider cache.

Any clue?

- Rider 2019.3
- Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-36682
The bug is already fixed, the fix is available in Rider 2019.3.1. Please, install the updates.